# Why do C programmers use typedefs to rename basic types?

Tags: c++, c

So I'm far from an expert on C, but something's been bugging me about code I've been reading for a long time: can someone explain to me why C(++) programmers use typedefs to rename simple types? I understand why you would use them for structs, but what exactly is the reason for declarations I see like

```
typedef unsigned char uch;
typedef uch UBYTE;
typedef unsigned long ulg;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef signed short s16;
```

Is there some advantage to this that isn't clear to me (a programmer whose experience begins with Java and hasn't ventured far outside of strictly type-safe languages)? Because I can't think of any reason for it--it looks like it would just make the code less readable for people unfamiliar with the project.

Feel free to treat me like a C newbie, I honestly know very little about it and it's likely there are things I've misunderstood from the outset. ;)

Comment: You should look at `stdint.h` .  Also they are used when the type of something may differ from system, but code needs to stay compatible.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Renaming types without changing their exposed semantics/characteristics doesn't make much sense. In your example

```
typedef unsigned char uch;
typedef unsigned long ulg;
```

belong to that category. I don't see the point, aside from making a shorter name.

But these ones

```
typedef uch UBYTE;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef signed short s16;
```

are a completely different story. For example, `s16` stands for "signed 16 bit type". This type is not necessarily `signed short`. Which specific type will hide behind `s16` is platform-dependent. Programmers introduce this extra level of naming indirection to simplify the support for multiple platforms. If on some other platform signed 16 bit type happens to be `signed int`, the programmer will only have to change one typedef definition. `UBYTE` apparently stands for an unsigned machine byte type, which is not necessarily `unsigned char`.

It's worth noting that the C99 specification already provides a standard nomenclature for integral types of specific width, like `int16_t`, `uint32_t` and so on. It probably makes more sense to stick with this standard naming convention on platforms that don't support C99.

Comment: +1 for recommending using the standard names but being more diplomatic about it than I would.. :-)

Comment: Haha, @R.., you put a smile on my face. :-)

Answer (score 14):

This allows for portability. For example you need an unsigned 32-bit integer type. Which standard type is that? You don't know - it's implementation defined. That's why you `typedef` a separate type to be 32-bit unsigned integer and use the new type in your code. When you need to compile on another C implementation you just change the `typedef`s.

Comment: This usage is deprecated because C has `uint32_t` etc.

Comment: @R: Only if your compiler has started implementing C99. Last I checked, Microsoft for one has not.

Comment: A compiler hardly has to implement C99 to have `inttypes.h` and `stdint.h`. If your compiler is missing them, simply drop-in replacements with the right definitions for your target architecture. There's no excuse for using nonstandard names.

Comment: @R: In which case you are effectively providing typedefs yourself anyway. Your approach is advisable, but not meaningfully different from adding typedefs to your project on your own.

Comment: @R: uint32_t *is* a typedef from stdint.h, so the usage is hardly deprecated.  It's merely standardised and done for you.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it is used to reduce an unwieldy thing like `volatile unsigned long` to something a little more compact such as `vuint32_t`.

Other times it is to help with portability since types like `int` are not always the same on each platform.  By using a typedef you can set the storage class you are interested in to the platform's closest match without changing all the source code.

Comment: to add to that, in c++, it can even go so far as to replace what may be a native type under the hood (like float) on one platform, with a whole class that emulates a float (such as for fixed point, on a platform with no floats)

Comment: Although, POSIX reserves type names ending with `_t`.

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons to it. What I think is:

1. Typename becomes shorter and thus code also smaller and more readable.
2. Aliasing effect for longer structure names.
3. Convention used in particular team/companies/style.
4. Porting - Have same name across all OS and machine. Its native data-structure might be slightly different.

Answer (score 4):

Following is a quote from The C Programming Language (K&R)

> Besides purely aesthetic issues, there are two main reasons for using
>   typedefs.

### First- to parameterize a program

> The first is to parameterize a program against portability problems.
>   If typedefs are used for data types
>   that may be machine-dependent, only
>   the typedefs need change when the
>   program is moved.
>
> *One common situation is to use typedef names for various integer
>   quantities, then make an appropriate
>   set of choices of short, int, and long
>   for each host machine.* Types like
>   size_t and ptrdiff_t from the standard library are examples.

The italicized portions tells us that programmers `typedef` basic type for portability. If I want to make sure my program works on different platforms, using different compiler, I will try to ensure that its portability in every possible way and `typedef` is one of them.

When I started programming using Turbo C compiler on Windows platform, it gave us the size of `int` 2. When I moved to Linux platform and GCC complier, the size I get is 4. If I had developed a program using Turbo C which relied on the assertion that `sizeof( int )` is always two, it would have not ported properly to my new platform.

Hope it helps.

Following quote from K&R is not related to your query but I have posted it too for the sake of completion.

### Second- to provide better documentation

> The second purpose of typedefs is to provide better documentation for a
>   program - a type called Treeptr may be easier to understand than one declared only as a
>   pointer to a complicated structure.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these patterns are bad practices that come from reading and copying existing bad code. Often they reflect misunderstandings about what C does or does not require.

1. Is akin to `#define BEGIN {` except it saves some typing instead of making for more.
2. Is akin to `#define FALSE 0`. If your idea of "byte" is the smallest addressable unit, `char` is a byte by definition. If your idea of "byte" is an octet, then either `char` is the octet type, or your machine has no octet type.
3. Is really ugly shorthand for people who can't touch type...
4. Is a mistake. It should be `typedef uint32_t u32;` or better yet, `uint32_t` should just be used directly.
5. Is the same as 4. Replace `uint32_t` with `int16_t`.

Please put a "**considered harmful**" stamp on them all. `typedef` should be used when you really need to create a new type whose definition could change over the life cycle of your code or when the code is ported to different hardware, not because you think C would be "prettier" with different type names.

Comment: Given that there's no context to the underlying arch the typedefs are compiled on, I don't think it's proper to ban them like that.
`char` is not an octet by definition. `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, and it does not mean *one byte*, but "*at least CHAR_BIT bits*" (CHAR_BIT may well be more than 8, albeit a rare sight nowadays). Also, all `[|u]intN_t` types, where N=8|16|32|64 and so forth, are defined per architecture in this exact manner. The only bad pattern is exposing `ulg` and `uch`, one could prefix them with `__` since they are in fact reserved names.

Comment: I never said char was an octet by definition. I said **either** char is an octet **or** your system has no octet type. This statement is completely true.

Comment: Also, you **cannot** (in an application) prefix those types with `__`. The **implementation** can (and must) do so if it makes such typedefs. I think you're very confused about what "reserved" means.

Answer (score 0):

We use it to make it Project/platform specific, everything has a common naming convention

`pname_int32, pname_uint32, pname_uint8` -- pname is project/platform/module name

And some #defines

```
pname_malloc, pname_strlen
```

It easier to read and shortens long datatypes like unsigned char to pname_uint8 also making it a convention across all modules.

When porting you need to just modify the single file , thus making porting easy.

Comment: Why do you need your own replacements for everything the standard library already provides?

Comment: @ R.. 
Is this fine?

#define pname_free(ptr) free(ptr)
#define pname_safe_free(ptr) \
if(ptr!=NULL) \
{ pname_free((void*) ptr); \
ptr =NULL;\
}

How about OEM functions too? Its looks not so readable when you replace the above macro and retain other standard names. May be its individual opinion again.

Comment: @R.. 
Microsoft specific keywords are __int8,__int16 etc.
How would you write code for Microsoft C compiler which will even compile on linux with gcc?
Does this make sense?

#ifdef(_MSC_VER)
typedef unsigned __int8 PNAME_INT
#elif defined(__GNUC)
typedef unsigned int8_t PNAME_INT
#endif

Comment: @Praveen, on broken compilers that lack the right **standard** types, simply provide a drop-in header that provides them with the standard names. There is no need for hideous `PNAME_` pollution. BTW your `pname_safe_free` macro is broken. Consider: `if (foo) pname_safe_free(foo); else ...`

Comment: Change it to `if (bar)` if it makes you happier. The point is that you'll get a compiler error at `else`. Function-like macros should **never** be wrapper in `{}`. Either use `((ptr)?(free((ptr)),(ptr)=0):0)` or wrap the code in `do { ... } while(0)`.

Comment: @Praveen, @R..: The C standard permits freeing a null pointer, the effect is a no-op. There is absolutely no need to check whether a pointer is null or not before calling free, because free will [probably] already check for null.

Comment: @R..: In any case, I think it would be better to go down the `do {...} while (0)` route for this, in case you provide the macro with an expression with side-effects (such as using `pname_safe_free(foo++)` in a loop, freeing an array of pointers.)

Comment: @R.. I still don't get it. When you have a macro which does the NULL check, why do you feel that one would call the macro with a preceding NULL check like `if(foo) pname_safe_free(foo)`. Would it not be just `pname_safe_free(foo)`. May be i am missing something here.

Comment: Arrg, you're missing the point. The condition is not the point, the syntax is the point. Your macro results in a syntax error when used as the "then" clause of an `if` statement with `else`. Replace the condition with `if (user_pressed_esc)` and stop thinking about it having anything to do with a NULL check.

Comment: @R.. Oh yeah i get the broken macro now.

Answer (score 0):

To cut the long story short,
you might want to do that to make your code portable (with less effort/editing).
This way you don't depend to 'int', instead you are using INTEGER that can be anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

All `[|u]intN_t` types, where N=8|16|32|64 and so forth, are defined per architecture in this exact manner. This is a direct consequence of the fact that the standard does not mandate that `char`,`int`,`float`, etc. have exactly N bits - that would be insane. Instead, the standard defines minimum and maximum values of each type as guarantees to the programmer, and in various architectures types may well exceed those boundaries. It is not an uncommon sight.

The `typedef`s in your post are used to defined types of a certain length, in a specific architecture. It's probably not the best choice of naming; `u32` and `s16` are a bit too short, in my opinion. Also, it's kind of a bad thing to expose the names `ulg` and `uch`, one could prefix them with an application specific string since they obviously will not be exposed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You absolutely **cannot** prefix them with `_` or `__`. These names are reserved **for the implementation** not for your application.

Comment: Only identifiers with one underscore following by an uppercase letter or another underscore are completely off lim

Comment: But it's still better to avoid _ prefixes at all.

Comment: What's point of using _ prefix? I think it only increases size and decreases readability of your code.